# Rotate code for obfuscation

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, uglifyjs

Is it possible to change the order of JavaScript code?

I am using grunt for concatenation, uglify and minify. To make reverse engineering more complicated, I thought of rotating the code from the concatenated code and then minify + uglify it.

Is this possible without breaking my code and is there something doing that?

Comment: Uglifying and minifying should provide adequate protection, even if "scrambling" were possible, which I'm not sure it is.

Answer (score 4):

I heard about https://jscrambler.com/en/ and it does not look bad :)

There is also a grunt task https://github.com/jscrambler/grunt-jscrambler

Note that obfuscated Javascript code is very difficult and in most cases the most convenient choice is just minify. There are several tools to deobfuscate it. However jscrambler seems to perform many transformations, making it much more hard to break.